# Do mirages in your stack gain more experience than those in your lineup?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

You can have a total of 12 mirages in your lineup at any one time, and obviously four of those can be used in your stacks.

Do mirages in your stacks gain more experience than those just in your lineup?

So if I'm working on levelling a certain mirage, would it be quicker to level it by putting it in my stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a tip for this in the Tip Jar.

[image: EXP Tip Jar panel]

So it seems that mirages in your stacks gain more benefit from your earned experience.